# Import Template File in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

### Question:

How do you import a simple text file into a typescript function?

### Details:

I am writing a simple command-line utility app that writes a text file out, injected with some parameters I collect from the user. I'm using the ejs templating engine to do this. This is *not* an express app.

I want the compile call to `tsc` to copy the compiled typescript code *and the non-typescript templates* to my distribution directory, but `tsc` won't copy files it doesn't need to transpile, so the files are missing when I run the compiled app.

### Solutions to Date:

#### Hacky copy of files

I could copy the files over as part of the build process like:

```
    "build": "yarn clean && yarn jest && tsc && cp -r src/templates dist/",
    "test": "jest"
  },
```

but this seems pretty hacky now that I'm calling out where to copy files  here instead of in `tscconfig.json`.

#### Install Webpack

I could use a bundler like Webpack, but it seems too complex a solution for my silly utility.

### The Dream

I'd love to just do something like this in my typescript file:

```
import myTemplateFile from "templates/my-templatefile"

...

function createPreferenceFile(preferences: PreferenceOptions) {

    const generatedFile = ejb.render(myTemplateFile,preferences);
    
    // write the generatedFile to the filesystem
}
```

Here's the content of my template file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.25
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <%=dbPassword%>
        MYSQL_DATABASE: <%=dbName%>
        MYSQL_USER: <%=dbUser%>
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: <%=dbPassword%>
    ports:
        - <%=dbPort%>:3306
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you okay if I gave a solution by changing the text file to JSON instead of a normal text? For JSON, I already have a rough idea about it.

Comment: I'm up for any ideas, @Nicholas, but doesn't tsc import json file already?

Comment: Sorry, it seems that I've misinterpreted the question. JSON won't work. If your template file is like that, it seems that the only way is to use the `fs` module? I'll let you know if I have any other ideas!